# What's the meaning of "tidy limbs" as a descriptor?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I am currently reading [The Radium Girls: The Dark Story of America’s Shining Women](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31409135-the-radium-girls). Near the start of chapter six it describes an individual as tidy limbed, what is the meaning of this phase?

> Catherine was a shy, quiet person who was very unassuming. She had thick, jet-black hair and very pale skin; a rather neat woman with **tidy limbs** who didn't go in for showy gestures.

[Emphasis mine]

I am aware of [Clean Limbed](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clean-limbed) which has a meaning of having well proportioned limbs, does tidy limbed mean the same?

The book was written in 2017 but is describing an individual alive in 1920 so may be using a more archaic version of a term.

Comment: I would have thought that the preceding "rather neat woman" and the following "who didn't go in for showy gestures" covers it. In other words, her limbs are not flying around everywhere, but are carefully placed.

Comment: Both ***clean*** and ***tidy*** have been around since the early 1300s with the sense ***neat, fair, fine, comely, attractive***.